# Why is a gif image displayed when used inside a picture element?

Tags: html5-img

I am trying to use a `picture` tag to show an animated image (gif), but it is not loading.

The same file loads fine when I use an `img` tag.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

```html
    <!-- This works -->
    <img src="./some.gif" />

    <!-- This does not work -->
    <picture>
        <source srcset="./some.gif" type="image/gif" />
    </picture>
```

Tried specifying `type="image/gif"`. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`<picture>` element is typically used for responsive images and allows you to provide multiple sources for different scenarios, like different screen sizes or formats.

In your case, since you're dealing with a GIF, which is a single image file, you might not need the  element. The  tag should suffice. The  element is more useful when dealing with multiple image sources.

Try simplifying it:

```
<!-- This should work -->
<img src="./some.gif" />
```

If you specifically need to use the  element, make sure there's a fallback  tag within it:

```
<!-- This could also work with the picture element -->
<picture>
    <source srcset="./some.gif" type="image/gif" />
    <img src="./some.gif" alt="Your Alternative Text">
</picture>
```

Comment: I am aware of `<picture>`'s use cases, and I know I could add an `<img>` as a fallback. I did check MDN pages of picture/source/img. The question is still why isn't it working when I specify a single gif source?

Comment: it's  due to the fact that the ```<picture>``` element is generally used for more complex scenarios with multiple sources, like different resolutions or formats. therefore it's recommended to replace ```<picture>``` with ```img ```instead